# React. Многоуровневое меню

Tags: reactjs

Есть JSON такого типа.

```js
{
  "nodes": [
    {
      "id": "abc_172.22.22.214",
      "name": "abc",
      "nodes": [
        {
          "id": "abc_172.22.22.214.if.1",
          "name": "0"
        },
        {
          "id": "abc_172.22.22.214.if.3",
          "name": "0"
        },
        {
          "id": "abc_172.22.22.214.if.2",
          "name": "0"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "MON_LOGS_192.168.1.53",
      "name": "MON_LOGS",
      "nodes": [
        {
          "id": "MON_LOGS_192.168.1.53.if.1",
          "name": "lo"
        },
        {
          "id": "MON_LOGS_192.168.1.53.if.2",
          "name": "eth0"
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

Необходимо создать многоуровневый список. Основной список формируется из имен устройств на первом уровне. При клике на любой nodes.name под ним должен разворачиваться дополнительный список устройств со своими именами. При повторном клике он должен исчезать.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);
     this.state = {
            data: data,
            displayChild: false,
        };
 }

    render () {
        let children = null;

        if(this.state.displayChild){
            children = <ul>                    
                            {this.state.data.nodes.map(element =>  
                             <li key={element.id}>{element.name}</li> 
                            )} 
                        </ul>
        }

        return(
            <div className='wrapper'>
                <ul>
                    {this.state.data.nodes.map(element => 
                        <li key={element.id} onClick={this.expandParent}>{element.name}{children}</li> 
                    )} 
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }    

    expandParent = () => {
        this.setState({
            displayChild: !this.state.displayChild
        })
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Я сформировал список основных устройств. Пытаюсь добавить функционал отображения вложенных списков, но не получается. При клике все элементы одновременно начинают отображать вложенные списки.

Также не могу сообразить, как правильно прописать, чтобы по клику функция map делала перебор только среди дочерних элементов выбранного устройства. Пробовал различные варианты - выдает ошибку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот то, что ты хотел

[Пример](https://codesandbox.io/s/30mz87o4m1)

```js
const data = {
  nodes: [
    {
      id: 'abc_172.22.22.214',
      name: 'abc',
      nodes: [
        {
          id: 'abc_172.22.22.214.if.1',
          name: '0'
        },
        {
          id: 'abc_172.22.22.214.if.3',
          name: '0'
        },
        {
          id: 'abc_172.22.22.214.if.2',
          name: '0'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 'MON_LOGS_192.168.1.53',
      name: 'MON_LOGS',
      nodes: [
        {
          id: 'MON_LOGS_192.168.1.53.if.1',
          name: 'lo'
        },
        {
          id: 'MON_LOGS_192.168.1.53.if.2',
          name: 'eth0'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: data,
    displayChild: null
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <ul>
          {this.state.data.nodes.map(element => (
            <li key={element.id} onClick={() => this.expandParent(element.id)}>
              {element.name}
              {element.id === this.state.displayChild && element.nodes && this._renderChildren(element.nodes)}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }

  _renderChildren = (nodes) => {
    const result = nodes.map(el => {
      return (<li key={el.id}> {el.name} </li>)
    });

    return (
      <ul>
        {result}
      </ul>
    )
  };

  expandParent = (id) => {
    this.setState({
      displayChild: id
    });
  };
}


const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Я использвал код, но один момент мне остался непонятен. В туториалах мне такая конструкция не попадалась, и как ее нагуглить - я не знаю)   Вот эта вот штука в блоке рендера -  {'  '}.    Для чего она или как называется?

Comment: Конкретно тут эта конструкция не требуется, это всего-лишь пробел который не удаляется.

В JSX:
1) Горизонтальный пробел сокращается до одного.
2) Если у вас есть пробел между элементами на одной линии, то всё это сократится до одного пробела.
3) Вертикальные пробелы стираются/

А конструкция {`     `} отрендерит точное кол-во пробелов сколько в ней есть.

Answer (score 3):

Можно создать компонент для отображения ноды. В стейте этого компонента хранить флаг развернутости, а также рекурсивно отрисовывать дочерние ноды.

```js
const items = {
  "nodes": [
    {
      "id": "abc_172.22.22.214",
      "name": "abc",
      "nodes": [
        {
          "id": "abc_172.22.22.214.if.1",
          "name": "Нода 1"
        },
        {
          "id": "abc_172.22.22.214.if.3",
          "name": "Нода 2"
        },
        {
          "id": "abc_172.22.22.214.if.2",
          "name": "Нода 3"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "MON_LOGS_192.168.1.53",
      "name": "MON_LOGS",
      "nodes": [
        {
          "id": "MON_LOGS_192.168.1.53.if.1",
          "name": "lo"
        },
        {
          "id": "MON_LOGS_192.168.1.53.if.2",
          "name": "eth0"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

class Node extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      expanded: false
    };
  }
  
  toggle = () => {
    let expanded = !this.state.expanded;
    this.setState({
      expanded: expanded
    });
  };
  
  showNodes() {
    let arNodes = [];
    if(this.props.element.nodes && this.props.element.nodes.length > 0) {
      this.props.element.nodes.map((element, index) => {
        arNodes.push(<Node key={index} element={element}/>);
      });
    }
    
    return arNodes;
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="panel panel-default">
        <div className="panel-heading">
        <button 
          type="button"
          onClick={this.toggle}
        >+</button>
        <h3>{this.props.element.name} <small>{this.props.element.id}</small></h3> 
        </div>
      {this.state.expanded && 
        <div className="panel-body">
          {this.showNodes()}
        </div>
      }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      {
      items.nodes.map(element =>  
        <Node 
          element={element}
        /> 
      )
      }
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div id="root"></div>
</div>
```